# MLKit for object detection for Android problem

Tags: android, object-detection, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to learn how to use ML-kit for Android for object detection. I wanted to choose an image from gallery and detect it in the device. My code is as follows:

First, I initialized Firebase a by :

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
```

Then, I created a listener for button as

```
 btnChooseImage.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent()
        intent.type = "image/*"
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "select Image"), 111)
    }
```

Then, after choosing image, I performed following code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 111) {
        imvImageRec.setImageURI(data?.data)

        val image: FirebaseVisionImage
        try {
            image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(applicationContext, data?.data!!)

            val labeler: FirebaseVisionImageLabeler = FirebaseVision.getInstance().onDeviceImageLabeler
            labeler.processImage(image).addOnSuccessListener {
                for (label in it) {
                    val text = label.text
                    val entityId = label.entityId
                    val confidence = label.confidence

                    txvRecognizedImageText.append("$text   $confidence\n")
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {

            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

I am having the problem in the line

```
val labeler: FirebaseVisionImageLabeler = FirebaseVision.getInstance().onDeviceImageLabeler
```

It says `NullPointerException`.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
> method 'com.google.firebase.ml.vision.label.FirebaseVisionImageLabeler
> com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVision.getOnDeviceImageLabeler()'
> on a null object reference
> at com.example.ObjectDetection.ObjectDetectionActivity.onActivityResult(ObjectDetectionActivity.kt:42)

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` <-- Where exactly are you doing this? In which class and method?

Comment: Also, if you're just getting started with this, then you might as well switch to [the non-Firebase ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) since it's replacing the Firebase ML Kit which has been deprecated.

Comment: hello @Michael . I have initialized firebase in onCreate

Comment: Thanks for the information @Michael i will look into non firebase ml kit as well.

Comment: `onCreate` of what? AFAIK you should do this in your `Application` class.

Comment: I would suggest to use the new ML Kit API as well. Here is the dev doc for object detection: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection/android (image labeling dev doc can be found on that site as well). Here is the sample app: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart In the sample app, there is an Activity doing detection on gallery images that you can refer to.